# Arduino/RPI module to control LED fairy lights with reverse polarity

Tags: arduino, led, raspberry-pi, h-bridge

I cant find any module to control my garland of lights by any embedded device. This module should be powered by DC12V input (but also possible to use Step Up/Step Down DC-DC voltage converter). The garland is controlled by two wires. Controller should rapidly change voltage polarity (tens times per sec) to control odd and even LEDs. It should change voltage in -35V..+35V range. Total power of the garland is less than 1A.

Does this task is too specific that needs soldering of custom board or there is a module to implement it? I suppose it is question about H-bridge module?

Thank you.

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic and quickly closed. It sounds like you need a 35 V PSU unless you cut the string into three 12 V sections and wire them in parallel.

Comment: why would you require a -35 V output?

Comment: -0..-35V for even LEDs and +0..+35V for odd LEDs - this is how original controller flashes LEDs with fade in/fade out effect